# Doxygen: How to reference a function, but with arguments values

Tags: c++, doxygen

When I generate the documentation for this class:

```
class MyClass
{
    /** Some description
     * \param inhibit some description
     */
    virtual void inhibitSaving( bool inhibit = true ) = 0;

    /** \return true if @ref inhibitSaving with parameter set to true has been called previously */
    virtual bool isSavinginhibited() const = 0;
};
```

`isSavinginhibited`'s description has a hyperlink to `inhibitSaving`.

However, if I write the description as below:

```
/** \return true if @ref inhibitSaving(true) has been called previously */
virtual bool isSavinginhibited() const = 0;
```

`isSavinginhibited`'s description does not have a hyperlink to `inhibitSaving`.

Considering [this discussion](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Linking-to-methods-and-mentioning-parameters-td1667.html#a1672), it's supposed to work. Why am I not getting a hyperlink. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the discussion, the example you have written above is not in the list Dimitri gives(true is not a type its a value). What you want seem to be \ref inhibitSaving(bool) "inhibitSaving(true)" or \ref inhibitSaving "inhibitSaving(true)"

Comment: @ArturKink: You are right, this works. You may want to post this as an answer to get deserved reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commented by ArturKink, `inhibitSaving(true)` is not a valid type reference, only `inhibitSaving(bool)` is.

So link should be created either like:

```
\ref inhibitSaving(bool) "inhibitSaving(true)"
```

**Or** like:

```
\ref inhibitSaving "inhibitSaving(true)"
```

Comment: Note: all doxygen commands work with "@" as well, hence `@ref inhibitSaving "inhibitSaving(true)"` would work as well.