# How can I @ref a different variant of the same method?

Tags: c++, comments, documentation, doxygen, cross-reference

I'm writing doxygen comments for some C++ code. I have two functions:

```
/** Some existing doxygen comment */
int foo(int x);

/** Another existing doxygen comment */
int foo(
    this_signature y1,
    is_really_long y2, 
    and_to_be_honest y3, 
    i_would y4, 
    really_rather y5, 
    avoid_repeating_it y6);

/** This is what I'm writing now */
int foo(double z);
```

In the doxygen comment for the second function, I want to refer, `@ref`, to the second function, or rather the second variant of the function. How do I do this?

Note: I am particularly (bot not solely) interested in a solution which would not be extremely verbose (considering the long signature of the second function).

Comment: I found [SO: Doxygen: How to reference a function, but with arguments values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42018482/7478597). According to the accepted answer, it looks like functions with signature can be referred. I must admit I've never tried this nor I know whether this works.

Comment: @Scheff: But that might be an extremely long string.

Comment: I found also in the Doxygen doc. [Automatic link generation Links to functions](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/autolink.html#Links_to_functions).

Comment: _But that might be an extremely long string._ I was not aware that you want something like short-cut. May be, it's worth to mention it in the question.

Comment: May be using an [`\anchor`](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdanchor)?

Comment: @Scheff: See edit

Answer (score 2):

It it (like @Scheff wrote) possible to reference by means of the signature. So something like:

```
/** Fie to show reference:
  *
  * \ref foo(unsigned long)
  *
  * \ref foo(unsigned long y)
  */
void fie(void);
```

See also http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html#linkfunc.

Regarding comment about long signatures, either use the `\anchor` possibility as suggested by @Scheff though, in my opinion, at first it looks a good solution but it is less maintainable (the signature variant is checked on existence when the documentation is generated, but the string in the of the `\ref` of the `\anchor` isn't (and you probably would need something like: `\ref my_anch "foo(unsigned long y)"` as otherwise (`\ref my_anch`) the link will have the name `my_anch` .

Comment: Ok, but - what if it's a really long signature? ... I edited my question to reflect that concern.